# CloudFormation is it part of the architecture of my project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I use **CDK** for all infrastructure on **AWS**, but has many problems *(problems like ROLLBACK, which a cant make deploy, need destroy all stacks related and then make deploy again)* with **CloudFormation** and people on work saying that should't not consider on part of my architecture and not should discuss about that. When say architecture i referer on all technologies i used to build my projects.

May I consider that I should discuss **CloudFormation** in my architecture and know and is it part?

Comment: This question is unclear.   There's no formal definition of architecture that excludes cloud formation per se.  But you should say more about what exactly you mean

Comment: You might want to include infrastructure as a code(IaaC) while discussing about your project architecture. Under IaaC, you can discuss about the technology/platforms you want to use. E.g. cloudformation, terrarium, serverless etc.

Comment: Updated with more information, can u guys look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It absolutely does make sense discussing CF/IaaC in the frame of your architecture.
It is defilitely "part".

I'd discuss this in [Deployment view](https://docs.arc42.org/section-7/).